# Marking sexp diary entries as done in org agenda

Tags: org-agenda, sexp

I often use sexp diary entries for events in ORG-AGENDA. Is there a way of marking them as "DONE" in agenda-view?

E.g. %%(diary-float t 2 3) Send John info for Bulletin

E.g. %%(diary-block 12 15 2018 1 8 2019) School Holidays